# What Python GUI software includes widgets that automate database transactions?

Tags: python, database, gui

To give you an idea what I mean, decades ago, before I retired, I would have used Delphi for this type of desktop application. In that software you can connect a table display to a database table or a SQL query and get essentially infinite scrolling for instance. You can move through a table a record at a time and display fields in the GUI.

Is there something like that for Python?

Comment: PyQt5 seems quite close, apart from the absence of an IDE.